# Can we capture log if we run a job from powershell

Tags: powershell, control-m

Can we capture logs if we run a job from power shell . As we are trying to run a control-m job from windows servers 2008 and its getting failed so we tried to run it from power shell . Is there any way to capture logs as job is failing in power shell also ?

Comment: Any command you try from Powershell can be logged using `$command |out-file $fileName`. 
Have you tried outputting the result this way?

Comment: ok let me give me a try...

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Start-Transcript`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff687007.aspx) for logging the actions/output of a script. You need to make sure the user running the script has write access to the output location.

```psh
Start-Transcript -Path 'C:\path\to\transcript.log' -Append

# production code here

Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: should we run from cmd ?

Comment: @Anurag Run what from CMD? The above is PowerShell code.